# oracle equivalent for position function in teradata

Tags: sql, oracle, teradata

Is there an equivalent function in Oracle to the POSITION function in teradata. http://www.sqlines.com/teradata/functions/position

In Teradata this function returns the index position of the first character of a matched word. For instance:

```
SELECT POSITION('Jose' IN 'San Jose');
   -- Result: 5
```

I'm trying to find a similar function in Oracle.

Comment: For not looking it up in the docs.

Comment: INSTR is more versatile than Standard SQL's POSITION, e.g. searching the nth position or searching backwards. That's why Teradata supports this, too, since TD14...

Answer (score 1):

INSTR, as documented in the documentation here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions068.htm

Answer (score 0):

Use **INSTR** in Oracle.

For example,

```
SQL> SELECT instr('San Jose','Jose',1) as "position" FROM dual;

  position
----------
         5
```

Read more about it in documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions068.htm).
    SQL>